# How can I change the color of a \enquote quotation inside Emacs?

Tags: latex, auctex, syntax-highlighting

When I paste a text inside quotation marks into Emacs+AUCTeX, AUCTeX formats it with a soft red color (see the screenshot below at the first line).

I like this color. However, I'm using `csquotes` package to handle (multilingual) quotations marks. The `\enquote` commands (provided by `csquote` package) use another color. I don't like this last color (see screenshot at the second line). With this ugly soft green color, I cannot find quickly quotation inside a big document.

How can I change `csquotes` default color to use AUCTeX default one?

### The screenshot:

[image]

(This screenshot uses French quotation marks but it hasn't any influence on my question.)

There is a bunch of settings about fontification in the csquotes.el file but I didn't see any reference to colors:

```
  ;; Fontification
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
          (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("DisableQuotes" "")
                ("RestoreQuotes" ""))
                  'function)
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("enquote" "*{")
                ("foreignquote" "*{{")
                ("hyphenquote" "*{{")
                ("textcquote" "*[[{[{")
                ("foreigntextcquote" "*{[[{[{")
                ("hyphentextcquote" "*{[[{[{")
                ("textquote" "*[[{")
                ("foreigntextquote" "*{[[{")
                ("hyphentextquote" "*{[[{")
                ("blockquote" "[[{")
                ("foreignblockquote" "{[[{")
                ("hyphenblockquote" "{[[{")
                ("blockcquote" "[[{[{")
                ("foreignblockcquote" "{[[{[{")
                ("hyphenblockcquote" "{[[{[{"))
                  'textual)
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("setquotestyle" "[{")
                ("MakeOuterQuote" "{")
                ("MakeInnerQuote" "{")
                ("MakeAutoQuote" "*{{")
                ("MakeForeignQuote" "*{{{")
                ("MakeHyphenQuote" "*{{{")
                ("MakeBlockQuote" "{{{")
                ("MakeForeignBlockQuote" "{{{{")
                ("MakeHyphenBlockQuote" "{{{{")
                ("DeclareQuoteStyle" "[{[[{[{[{[{")
                ("DeclareQuoteAlias" "[{{")
                ("DeclareQuoteOption" "{")
                ("DeclarePlainStyle" "{{{{")
                ("SetBlockThreshold" "{")
                ("SetBlockEnvironment" "{")
                ("SetCiteCommand" "{"))
                  'variable)))))

;;; csquotes.el ends here
```

Comment: Here is the link to the same thread posted on tex.stackexchange:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179037/26911

Answer (score 1):

This is a general approach, so you can use it to customize any other faces:

1. Place your cursor under the word whose color you want to change and <kbd>M-x</kbd>`describe-char`.
2. You will be prompted with some information. Check *There are text properties here:* section, and copy the face link text. (something like `font-lock-keyword-face` for example)
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> and paste the previously copied text (for instance `font-lock-keyword-face` in this case) <kbd>RET</kbd>.
4. Modify the color and click/enter *Apply and Save*.

Comment: Thank you for describe-char. When wanting to inspect text properties in the past I've always written a snippet in scratch-buffer! No more!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `font-latex-user-keyword-classes`, e.g.

```
(setq font-latex-user-keyword-classes
      '(("quotes" '("enquote" "*{") font-latex-string-face command))))
```

, as described in the info manual `(info "(auctex) Fontification of macros")`.  Note that changing this variable may require a restart of Emacs.  Also, I don't know what happens in case of multiple definitions, i.e. by this variable *and* by your package.